# Removing max edges while keeping minimum distance

Tags: algorithm

Suppose we have a graph with vertices from 1 to n.The graph is undirected and the starting point is 1 and we have path from 1 to any other vertex.We also have positive weight on each edge and  there are two types of edges - black and red.
The black edges are in the form (1,x) where x is a vertex and red edges can be any pair (x,y) .My question is how can I find the maximum number of black edges I can remove so that the minimal distance from 1 to any other vertex is preserved?

Comment: Please pick the language you want to use, not two languages C and C++. However, this is only provided you are actually asking a question about a particular language, which you don't, which is the reason I removed both tags. As a new user, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: The maximum weight black edges or just maximum number?

Comment: maximum number of black edges

Answer (score 2):

Something like this. Using your favorite path-finding algorithm, find a shortest path from 1 to each other vertex using a cost function of `{total weight, number of black edges}`. This would produce paths that prefer red edges, other things equal.

You can now remove all black edges that don't belong to any path.

Comment: I didn't quite get the idea,can you elaborate?

Comment: Do you mean that I should find the shortest path from 1 to each vertex and store the black edges from these paths in a set for example .Then the answer will be the total black edges - the size of the set?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. The key here is tweaking the cost function so the path finding avoids black edges as much as possible. In other words, if there are multiple paths with the same total weight, it'd pick one containing fewest black edges.

Comment: To get the right answer, I think your path-finding algorithm always has to pick the red in the event of a tie. Which you've specified, nm.

Comment: For ties, they can sometimes be removed if the cost function is `{total weight, black edge weight}`, I think.

Comment: If the targets of two black edges of the same weight are connected by a 0-length red edge, then there is no objective metric that can distinguish between them.  So, sort the black edges by weight, note their indexes in the sorted list, starting at 1.  A viable cost function would then be {total_weight, sum_of_black_edge_indexes}.